# permission denied in docker entrypoint

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, permission-denied, docker-entrypoint

I am trying to to run an entrypoint script via docker-compose file. And im getting permission denied error while trying to edit a configuration while. I have tried with root user as well with no luck.

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7 AS ingestbase
RUN mkdir -p ${USER_HOME}/certs ${USER_HOME}/logs
COPY config/*  ${USER_HOME}/
RUN useradd -m -d ${USER_HOME} user
RUN chown -R user ${USER_HOME}/ 
USER user
WORKDIR ${USER_HOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Entrypoint.sh is as below:

```
set -x
TRY_LOOP="3"
who
pwd
ls -ltr
sed -i "s#{DB_PASS}#$DB_PASS#g" ${USER_HOME}/config.py
```

Following are the logs while running enrypoint.sh

```
+ TRY_LOOP=3
+ who
/usr/local/userhome
+ pwd
+ ls -ltr
total 10
drwxr-xr-x 9 user root  4096 Sep 20 02:51 logs
drwxr-xr-x 1 user root     6 Sep 25 05:59 certs
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root 41558 Sep 25 05:59 config.py
sed: couldn't open temporary file /usr/local/userhome/sedjzy3se: Permission denied
```

Comment: Where is the variable `$USER_HOME` set?  (You could set `WORKDIR /usr/local/userhome` at the top of the Dockerfile, and then it would be the current directory `.`; you don't really need this variable.)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't have executable permission on the entrypoint.

Have you tried doing:

```
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Comment: If it helps anybody, `ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "/path/to/entrypoint.sh"]` worked for me on Azure App Service with Custom Docker container.